# Django Listview.as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django

Use Listview instead of list_detail in django and failed.

How to fix this?

I want to get all the books where publisher == name(name from url).

**TypeError at /app_generic_view/books/test/**

as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
def books_by_publisher(request, name):
    publisher = get_object_or_404(Publisher, name=name)
    return ListView.as_view(request, queryset=Book.objects.filter(publisher=publisher),
        template_name='publisher_list_page.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function books_by_publisher() takes a request as argument. So I assume this is a view. It should return a HttpResponse instance or one of the derived class.

Instead, you return ListView.as_view(). ListView.as_view() is a method returning a view (a python function). as_view() cannot take a request as argument, and doesn't return a HTTP response.

The right way to use Django class based view is to subclass one of the pre-defined class and use as_view() in your urlpatterns to get the corresponding view function.

Example:

```
# models.py
class MyCustomView(ListView):
    model = Publisher
    template_name = publisher_list_page.html

# urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^a_pattern/(?P<name>[a-z]+)', MyCustomView.as_view(), name='a_name'),
]
```

Comment: You need to override `get_queryset` and filter on the publisher name as well.

Answer (score 0):

To call a view from another you should use :

```
return ListView.as_view()(request, queryset=Book.objects.filter(publisher=publisher),
        template_name='publisher_list_page.html')
```

Comment: The `queryset` and `template_name` arguments should still be passed to `as_view`:  `return ListView.as_view(queryset=Book.objects.filter(publisher=publisher),
        template_name='publisher_list_page.html')(request)`. However, subclassing list view as in @Antwane's answer would be a better approach.